Configure AWS event pattern for redshift function execution status
I am trying to receive SNS notification once the data load is completed in my redshift tables. For this I have been requested to look if we can create some kind of rule in eventbridge and then create an SNS topic to receive email notifications. I was trying to create one even pattern for redshift load for tables but wasn't able to find any event type in redshift data event, so I started looking into "Redshift Data Statement Status Change" event type to see if my function execution is finished or not since I am loading the table using the function. Below is the pattern I've created:
{
  "source": ["aws.redshift-data"],
  "detail-type": ["Redshift Data Statement Status Change"],
  "detail": {
    "database": ["my_db"],
    "schema": ["my_schema"],
    "object-type": ["function"],
    "object-name": ["daily_load_fnc"],
    "state": ["FINISHED","FAILED"]
  }
}


Is this the correct pattern to achieve the notification as I am not sure of this is gonna work or is there any other way I can create event pattern directly by specifying the target as tables. I have looked into aws documentation regarding calling apis/executing sql statement but didn't find anything for this case.

{

  "source": ["aws.redshift-data"],

  "detail-type": ["Redshift Data Statement Status Change"],

  "detail": {

    "database": ["my_db"],

    "schema": ["my_schema"],

    "object-type": ["function"],

    "object-name": ["daily_load_fnc"],

    "state": ["FINISHED","FAILED"]

  }

}





I haven't tried doing this -- and don't know whether there even is an event for a Data API state change -- but I would expect it to return the query ID and not any information from inside the query (similar to what you get for an Athena query state change event). I recommend that you create a dummy Lambda that just prints its invocation event, and send all Data API events to it, so that you can see exactly what you get.
